# How to pass user role and file no from action to action using hidden fields?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I work on `asp.net mvc`. I face the issue that I can't pass user role and User code from `IndexResignation` action to `PendingManagersRequests` action using Hidden Fields.

so: How to use Hidden fields.

```
 public ActionResult IndexResignation(string filenumber)
 {
     int employeeFileNo;
     string userRole;
     
     if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(filenumber))
     {
         
         if (int.TryParse(filenumber, out employeeFileNo))
         {
             JDEUtility jde = new JDEUtility();
             userRole = Workforce.ResignationGetUserRole(employeeFileNo);    
            
             Session[SessionKeys.UserCode] = employeeFileNo;
             if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(userRole))
             {                     
                 Session[SessionKeys.RoleCode] = userRole;
             }
          
             if (userRole == RoleKey.LM || userRole == RoleKey.DM || userRole == RoleKey.LDM)
             {                     
                 return RedirectToAction("PendingManagersRequests", "Resignation", null);
             }                                     
         }
         else
         {
             ViewBag.errorMsg = "incorrect file no";
         }
     }
     else
     {
         ViewBag.errorMsg = "unauthorized user";
     }
    
     return View();
 }

 public async Task<ActionResult> PendingManagersRequests(string msg, string errorMsg)
 {
    // how to pass user role and user code to action PendingManager
 }
```

Can you show me view and action what will be if I use hidden fields?

`Index resignation` action does not have a view

`PendingMangerRequest` action does have a view

**updated post**

can you show me please by code sample if possible

I mean, like the code sample in the comment above

Comment: "hidden fields" are client-side inputs - ie in the HTML.   As you use `RedirectToAction("PendingManagersRequests"` there's no HTML yet, so "hidden fields" are not relevant / *not available*.   Just pass the values as parameters:  `return RedirectToAction("PendingManagersRequests", "Resignation", null, employeeFileNo, userRole)` and update the PendingManagersRequests signature accordingly.

Comment: can you show me please by code sample if possible

Comment: You mean, like the code sample in the comment above?

Comment: `return RedirectToAction("PendingManagersRequests", "Resignation", null, employeeFileNo, userRole)`

Comment: and what i write on PendingManagersRequests to recieve value

Comment: `public async Task<ActionResult> PendingManagersRequests(string msg, string errorMsg, int exployeeFileNo, string userRole)`